# Mule HTTP POST request returns 302 page redirect

Tags: http, redirect, post, mule

I have a flow that sends an HTTP POST request to a web service. Rather than returning the expected SOAP XML response, it returns with a page redirect.
When testing the service, I use SOAPUI. I use the same URL and POST request with the same body. I get actual data. No page redirects.

My flow looks like the following:

```
<flow name="webService_Flow">
   <http:listener 
        config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" 
        path="/getWS" 
        allowedMethods="GET" 
        doc:name="HTTPS"/>
    <parse-template 
        location="templates/ws.template" 
        mimeType="text/xml"
        doc:name="Parse Template"/>
    <http:request 
        config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" 
        path="${webservice.request.path}" 
        method="POST" 
        doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:failure-status-code-validator values="302"/>
    </http:request>
    <flow-ref 
        name="transformWS_subflow" 
        doc:name="Transform WS"/>
    <logger 
        message="#[message]"
        level="INFO"
        category="HTTP_MESSAGE" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The HTTP Request connector looks like the following:

```
<http:request-config 
    name="HTTP_Request_Configuration"
    protocol="HTTPS" 
    host="${webservice.host}"
    basePath="${webservice.path}"
    port="${webservice.port}"
    followRedirects="false"
    doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```

I have verified the URL, the paths, the port, and the protocol. Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: I even tried using the web service consumer connector. I get page redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the followRedirects to true should do the trick. You are setting it to false in your config so any redirects received will be returned as is. HTH

Comment: Still get page redirect to web page. No data. I have a nearly identical flow to another service. It works. This is what perplexes me.

Comment: Can you try with the followRedirects="true" plus sending an explicit Host header to whatever the host is? I've seen something similar when the server could not handle the implicit Host header sent which includes the port.

Comment: No success, but it did return with a 404 page instead of a 302 page redirect. I will tinker with it some, you may have something there.

Comment: My solution, for the time being, was to just write that part in Java.

Comment: Found the issue with our F5 front end, Tomcat 8 server, and explicitly setting the port number (which Mule HTTP requires). When Mule sends the request with the port number, it doesn't match the proper URL according to irules and redirects.

Comment: Weird that the explicit host header didn't work then. Glad you could find the issue.